# Merge or link contacts programmatically in iOS 9+

Tags: ios, contacts

iOS 9+ introduced a new [Contact framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/contacts) that handles well unified contacts from various sources. Unfortunately, I have not been able to find a nice way to merge or link together contacts programmatically.

Having to iterate over all the possible properties of a contact sounds like an awful way to deal with this, and I will certainly miss some properties that will be added in a near future.

Has anyone encountered this problem, and if so, how did you handle it?
Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52670973/cant-add-unified-cncontact-to-cngroup-in-ios ?

Comment: Not really: I'd like here to merge contact, or link them programmatically even if they are not from different sources.

Comment: I don't know what you imagine "link ... even if they are not from different sources" means. And I don't see what you imagine you would do to merge contacts except to iterate over them and manipulate them directly; it's not going to happen by magic. The q-and-a that I linked to makes clear that there is no API for linking. So I think this _is_ a duplicate.

Comment: I really don't think it is. The post you mentioned raises the issue of accessing individual and unified contacts. In my case, all I wanna do is really _link_ the contacts together.